# Retrieving a web view url once the url changes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, ios6

I have a NSTimer that calls this method every second or so so i can update a URL label

```
-(void)update {
NSString *currentURL = theView.request.URL.absoluteString;
theURL.text = currentURL;
}
```

I really dont like using a timer, it works but i would rather have it change only once the web views url changes, are there any methods for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) that being called every-time webview start another url.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *currentURL = [[request URL] absoluteString] ;

    return YES;
}
```

But remember, to set delegate into your `webview`.

Comment: Works perfectly! But why am I getting this warning on the last line of that method? Control reaches end of non-void function?